# Laravel relationship - reference with static class or string?

Tags: php, laravel, static, relationship

In this example, I have a `Reward` model, and I'm defining a relationship to a category. Which is better practice, and why?

Referencing the relationship statically:

`public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category');
}`

or via a string:

`` public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category`, 'category');
} ``

I would think the string method makes more sense since there isn't a direct reference to another model, but I could be wrong. I want to make sure things are setup properly according to best standards, but couldn't find an opinion on this anywhere.

Comment: I guess it might be considered opinion based, but `Category::class` is better. It can advantage `use App\Category;` to shorten it and also PHP resolves it correctly every time. IDEs are able to help with autocomplete as well. With strings you need to write it down and hope you don't misspell it.

Comment: Referencing as a string will help ensure you don't run into namespace issues when you are building larger applications. It also provides some clarity about where the relationship is going which makes it easier to maintain. As @apokryfos said it is opinion based.

Comment: Another benefit of using `Category::class` to reference a class is that you don't need to change the references to other models in your current namespace if, for whatever reason, you have to change the namespace or rename it. Think of it like the difference between absolute and relative paths.